# Remove Eclipse scroll bars

Tags: eclipse, themes

Any ideas on how to remove or change the color of the vertical and horizontal scroll bars in Eclipse? They show even when everything is visible on the screen, and are quite unappealing with a dark theme. Link to pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIkKe.jpg

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure your scroll bar colors are set based on your desktop theme. Seems a tad ocd :P

Comment: @zgc7009 I tried to edit the scroll bar colors in "advanced settings" in the theme area, but only the size was selectable.

Answer (score 0):

just change associated editor that you use for you current file.
go  `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations` and choose another adapted for this kind of file

[image: Example]